# Input function don´t show and is "blank" in print

Tags: python, input

I´m new to python and uses the latest version of 3.7 on mac 64bit.
When put in following code and run model, my name don´t show: " Its good to meet you, (blank)!"

What is wrong?

```
print('Hello World')
print('Whats your name?')
myname = input ('Alexander') 
print('Its good to meet You,' + myname +'!')
```

Comment: Check which version of python you are using, the default on Mac is Python 2 where `input()` has different functionality to python 3.

Comment: 3.7.2, so this should be correct..?

Answer (score 1):

The input function expects user input while the function is running, eg `input()` and then you would type your name in the terminal. "Alexander" should be shown in the terminal with your current code.
Try

```
print('Hello World')
myname = input('Whats your name?') 
print('Its good to meet You,' + myname +'!')
```

Then type "Alexander" in the command prompt

[More info here](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_input.php)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but the problems is after I run this program and type "myname" then Alexander should come up but instead it only show " "

Answer (score 0):

The input function is used to let the user inputs string after the start.
You have to type something when it sais alexandre

Answer (score 0):

it seems you put a space after input function. instead of

```
print('Whats your name?')
myname = input ('Alexander')
```

Try this

```
myname = input("Whats your name? ")
```

and after running this code when this ask for name just type in your name

the comple code will look like this

```
print('Hello World')
myname = input("Whats your name? ")
print('Its good to meet You, {} !'.format(myname))
```

Comment: Thanks for Your input, but even without a space my problem still exits.. After running this program and I print "myname" it dont show up instead: " "